# Can I tune this SQL in this way?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

```sql
select count(*) from attachment where status = 1;
```

There are about 45k rows in the table. most of their status values are gathering in value 1, which is about 37k rows.

This query cost about 30ms, and it's a high-frequency invoking.

So can I tune the performace by adding index to `status` column, or how could I tune the performace?

Comment: nop, you can use b-tree to explain this

Comment: Try it and see?

Answer (score 3):

You could try an index on `daw_attachment(status)`.  However, this would just replace scanning the table with scanning the index.  That is faster, but the optimizer still needs to read all 37k values.

The alternative is to use triggers to maintain the count in some other table.  That incurs overhead whenever the table is modified.  If the updates are very frequent, the trigger could affect performance.

Comment: In practice, the cost of updating another table from a trigger is about the same as updating any index, even an index in the same table.